# Repetitive images in fancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have a fancyBox which works well besides the fact, that on certain images it slides the same image for few times. Here is the [web page](http://feanor.cz/portfolio/car-photo/).

I do not use any other jQuery or my own scripts, only fancyBox scripts.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
/*! fancyBox v2.1.5 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
 position: relative;
 background: #f9f9f9;
 color: #444;
 text-shadow: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
         border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
 z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
         box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
 position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
 color: #444;
 font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
 background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}

#fancybox-loading {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -22px;
 margin-left: -22px;
 background-position: 0 -108px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
 position: absolute;
 top: -18px;
 right: -18px;
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
 left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 36px;
 height: 34px;
 margin-top: -18px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 8040;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
 left: 10px;
 background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
 right: 10px;
 background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
 visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
 position: absolute;
 top: -99999px;
 left: -99999px;
 visibility: hidden;
 max-width: 99999px;
 max-height: 99999px;
 overflow: visible !important;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto;
}

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-lock-test {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
 z-index: 8010;
 background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
 visibility: hidden;
 font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: none;
 z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
 visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 50%;
 margin-bottom: -35px;
 z-index: 8050;
 text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -100%;
 padding: 2px 20px;
 background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
         border-radius: 15px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 24px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/*Retina graphics!*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){

 #fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
  background-image: url('fancybox_sprite@2x.png');
  background-size: 44px 152px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
 }

 #fancybox-loading div {
  background-image: url('fancybox_loading@2x.gif');
  background-size: 24px 24px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
 }
}
```

```css
#albums-bar-shape {
    width: 1141px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    /*background-color: #e7e7e7;*/
}

#album {
    width: 1150px;
    height: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    position: relative;
    /*background-color: #afd9ee;*/
    top: 20px;
}

.albums-bar {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: -50%;
}

.albums-bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

.albums-bar li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.albums-bar a {
    color: #8c8c8c;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Arial", "Courier New";
    text-decoration: none;
}

.albums-bar a:hover {
    color: #222222;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#selected-album {
    color: #222222;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
}
/*Vertical photos formatting*/
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 275px;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/*Horizontal photos formatting*/
div.img-wide {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 370px;
}

div.img-wide:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img-wide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/img-noise-361x370.png (1));
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#top {
    width: 650px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    /*background-color: #e7e7e7;*/
}

#menu-bar {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: -50%;
}

#menu-bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#menu-bar li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 55px;
}

#menu-bar a {
    color: #8c8c8c;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Arial", "Courier New";
    text-decoration: none;
}

#selected {
    color: #000000;
}

#selected > a {
    color: #000000;
}

#menu-bar a:hover {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#images {
    width: 533px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    position: relative;
    /*background-color: #afd9ee;*/
}

#logo {
    width: 650px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
    display: block;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Arial", "Courier New";
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /*background: #dddddd;*/
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: 8c8c8c;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10pt !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: #565656;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/dropdown.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/crossfade.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/portfolio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../src/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <title>Car Photos</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="logo" src="http://feanor.cz/images/logo_studio.gif">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="menu-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/fashion-photo">Photo</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/fashion-photo">Fashion portraits</a>
                        <a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/art-photo">Art portraits</a>
                        <a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/product-photo">Product photography</a>
                        <a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/interior-photo">Interior photography</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Paintings</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/contacts">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/about">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="albums-bar-shape">
        <div class="albums-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/fashion-photo">Fashion portraits</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/art-photo">Art portraits</a></li>
                <li><a id="selected-album" href="#">Car photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/product-photo">Product photography</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://feanor.cz/portfolio/interior-photo">Interior photography</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="album">
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="1.jpg">
                <img src="1.jpg" alt="image 1" width="300" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="2.jpg">
                <img src="2.jpg" alt="image 2" width="300" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="6.jpg">
                <img src="6.jpg" alt="image 3" width="300" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="4.jpg">
                <img src="4.jpg" alt="image 4" width="300" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="5.jpg">
                <img src="5.jpg" alt="image 5" width="300" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="3.jpg">
                <img src="3.jpg" alt="image 6" width="300" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="7.jpg">
                <img src="7.jpg" alt="image 7" width="300" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wide">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="8.jpg">
                <img src="8.jpg" alt="image 8" width="300" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close a few of the anchor tags. #6 and #3.
As a result, the browser adds another link which makes fancyBox think there are duplicate images. Here's how Chrome is compiling the code:

[image]